# How to prevent Spotless/Eclipse from joining lines?

Tags: java, eclipse, spotless

I have a project that uses [Spotless with the Eclipse formatter](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/master/plugin-gradle#eclipse-jdt) to check and format the source code.

Now *one* problem is that the formatter creates some absurdly long lines such as the following:

```
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This is a placeholder text but the real text is just as long as this.", required = true, example = "811769e0-69f8-11e6-91aa-02000ab20f88")
```

That’s 170 characters, and I got eye-strain and SonarQube complaining. When I break the line, Spotless/Eclipse insist on joining the lines together. The configuration file has lines such as:

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit" value="150"/>
```

The file is picked up fine, but the formatter still joins these wrapped lines and would never split them. There seems to be a related ancient (and closed) [issue 338916](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338916) in the Eclipse bug tracker. This is probably not a Spotless configuration issue, since it delegates everything to the Ecplipse plugin. Which magic configuration key will persuate the Eclipse formatter to behave as advertised?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 1):

I used similar spotless eclipse formatter settings and still ran into the same issue with the formatter joining wrapped API documentation lines into a single long line. What I ended up doing was enabling [toggle comments](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle#spotlessoff-and-spotlesson) and putting them around the lines I didn't want joined. Wrapped lines that are surrounded by the toggle comments remain wrapped. Sample below:

```
    // spotless:off
    @Operation(summary = "getImagePullCount",
               description = "Generates the docker pulls badge",
               responses = @ApiResponse(description = "An XML representing the SVG docker pulls badge",
                                        content = @Content(mediaType = CONTENT_TYPE_BADGE,
                                        schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class))))
    public String getImagePullCount(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                                               description = ApiSpecConstants.API_DESC_PARAM_PACKAGE,
                                               example = ApiSpecConstants.EXAMPLE_PARAM_PACKAGE)
                                    @QueryValue("package") String packageName,
                                    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                                               description = ApiSpecConstants.API_DESC_PARAM_LABEL)
                                    @QueryValue(value = "label", defaultValue = "docker pulls") String badgeLabel) {
    // spotless:on
```